# UserForm If then Loop Issue VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to have my userform require a combobox selection if a specific text box is used.  For instance, If Textbox2 has information entered into it, The user must make a selection in ComboBox1.  If TextBox6 has information, then ComboBox2 is required.

I have the below code that works for the first set in requiring a ComboBox selection, however, it does not enter the desired information once all the required info is filled in.

Furthermore, once I start to use more lines within the Userform, everything goes out of whack.  It starts saying data needs to be entered on lines that nothing is entered or adding adjustments to the worksheet based on textboxes that arent in the right order.

I am assuming it has something to do with all the If Then statements and the ordering in the loop.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim N As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim Rng3 As Range
Dim Rng4 As Range
Dim Rng5 As Range
Dim Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean


Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set Rng1 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox2.Value)
Set Rng2 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox6.Value)
Set Rng3 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox5.Value)
Set Rng4 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox4.Value)
Set Rng5 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox7.Value)

N = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox2, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox2) = 0 And ComboBox1 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox2 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox3.Value = "" And ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    End If
    
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox6, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox6) = 0 And ComboBox2 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox6 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox8.Value = "" And ComboBox2.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    End If
    
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox5, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox5) = 0 And ComboBox3 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox5 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox9.Value = "" And ComboBox3.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    End If
    
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox4, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox4) = 0 And ComboBox4 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox4 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox10.Value = "" And ComboBox4.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    End If
    
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox7, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox7) = 0 And ComboBox5 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox7 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox11.Value = "" And ComboBox5.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    End If

For i = 5 To N
    If TextBox2.Text > 0 Then
        If ComboBox1.ListIndex < 0 Then
            MsgBox "You must select an adjustment!", vbCritical
            Cancel = True
        Else
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox1.Value Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng1.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox3.Text
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    If TextBox6.Text > 0 Then
        If ComboBox2.ListIndex < 0 Then
            MsgBox "You must select an adjustment!", vbCritical
            Cancel = True
        Else
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox2.Value Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng2.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox8.Text
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    
    If TextBox5.Value > 0 Then
        If ComboBox3.ListIndex < 0 Then
            MsgBox "You must select an adjustment!", vbCritical
            Cancel = True
        Else
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox3.Value Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng3.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox9.Text
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    If TextBox4.Value > 0 Then
        If ComboBox4.ListIndex < 0 Then
            MsgBox "You must select an adjustment!", vbCritical
            Cancel = True
        Else
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox4.Value Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng4.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox10.Text
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    If TextBox7.Value > 0 Then
        If ComboBox5.ListIndex < 0 Then
            MsgBox "You must select an adjustment!", vbCritical
            Cancel = True
        Else
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox5.Value Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng5.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox11.Text
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i

ErrorHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

The issue I am having is with this section

```
For i = 5 To N
    If TextBox2.Text > 0 Then
        If ComboBox1.ListIndex < 0 Then
            MsgBox "You must select an adjustment!", vbCritical
            Cancel = True
        Else
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox1.Value Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng1.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox3.Text
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    If TextBox6.Text > 0 Then
        If ComboBox2.ListIndex < 0 Then
            MsgBox "You must select an adjustment!", vbCritical
            Cancel = True
        Else
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox2.Value Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng2.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox8.Text
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    
    If TextBox5.Value > 0 Then
        If ComboBox3.ListIndex < 0 Then
            MsgBox "You must select an adjustment!", vbCritical
            Cancel = True
        Else
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox3.Value Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng3.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox9.Text
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    If TextBox4.Value > 0 Then
        If ComboBox4.ListIndex < 0 Then
            MsgBox "You must select an adjustment!", vbCritical
            Cancel = True
        Else
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox4.Value Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng4.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox10.Text
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    If TextBox7.Value > 0 Then
        If ComboBox5.ListIndex < 0 Then
            MsgBox "You must select an adjustment!", vbCritical
            Cancel = True
        Else
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox5.Value Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng5.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox11.Text
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: If you're only going to have one combobox used, why not populate a single combobox based on the data entered to either a single textbox, or by checking which textbox is filled out?

Comment: There's 5 lines on the userform.  Each line has a textbox to enter an ID, a combobox to select and adjustment type and then another textbox with the adjustment amount.  Each line is separate from each other.  If someone enters an ID in the first textbox, I need it to require a combobox selection.  It can be populated if an ID is entered into the first textbox because there could be multiple adjustments that they would have to choose from

Comment: You really need to refactor this or the maintenance will be a nightmare - name your controls using a pattern which allows you to address one "row" at a time, and use a loop with (eg) `Me.Controls("txtID" & i)`,`Me.Controls("cmbAdj" & i)`, `Me.Controls("txtAmt" & i)` to access each control on line `i`